# Using different x-axis labels for n lines in a graph

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

So I am using MPAndroidChart as library for the viewing of graphs in my app. Now I wanted to make a LineGraph with several lines (n). The problem is that those lines do not have the same x-axis labels and I have not found a solution to put the x-axis labels in relation to the entries. Furthermore does the new line start at x-value 0. Therefore my lines do not fill the entire diagram area. Because when I have two lines with 6 entries each, the x-axis labels have the size 12. And therefore the lines end at half of the diagram.

How do I solve that?

[Example LineGraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WYCO.png)

Answer (score 4):

I assume you mean the library available here: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/LineChartActivity2.java

From the code I grasped, LineChart does not support dual x-axis (while it support dual y-axis, left and right). See [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/tree/master/MPChartLib/src/com/github/mikephil/charting/components) , XAxis.java and YAxis.java

On the other hand, looks like the x-axis fits the data range automatically (there is no method to set min/max of x-axis).

An example of the graph [>>](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/screenshots/linechart_multiline.png)

I would suggest you to re-organize your chart to switch x and y axis, and use two y axis if your series have different range of y values, but you want to show them in a chart.  Double y-axis is more common than double x-axis from my experience, and easier to understand as well.